# Creating a menu from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, menu

I have got the following pulled from an array.

```
[TheBeautifulSouth/2-15 One Last Love Song.m4a] => Array
    (
        [name] => TheBeautifulSouth/2-15 One Last Love Song.m4a
        [time] => 1296612503
        [size] => 7628998
        [hash] => 4c6d9b19310ad53efccc5df2e0632e82
    )

[TheBeautifulSouth/2-16 Mirror.m4a] => Array
    (
        [name] => TheBeautifulSouth/2-16 Mirror.m4a
        [time] => 1296612568
        [size] => 8418448
        [hash] => ef371e227b410bb4c9ed1ff7f2d0d70e
    )

[TheBeautifulSouth/2-17 One God.m4a] => Array
    (
        [name] => TheBeautifulSouth/2-17 One God.m4a
        [time] => 1296612639
        [size] => 8619393
        [hash] => 80f29fbef6f469e3f150f7011a320987
    )

[TheBeautifulSouth/2-18 Blackbird On the Wire (Radio Ed.m4a] => Array
    (
        [name] => TheBeautifulSouth/2-18 Blackbird On the Wire (Radio Ed.m4a
        [time] => 1296612712
        [size] => 6776214
        [hash] => fe13ced4b9fc26b013c241219c642095
    )

[dnb/] => Array
    (
        [name] => Music/dnb/
        [time] => 1296576896
        [size] => 0
        [hash] => d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
    )

[dnb/03 Twerk feat. Yo Majesty (Sub Focus Remix).mp3] => Array
    (
        [name] => dnb/03 Twerk feat. Yo Majesty (Sub Focus Remix).mp3
        [time] => 1296577218
        [size] => 11782889
        [hash] => 372e32ad1aff44061b65f5a76e7e805c
    )

[Music/dnb/21st Century (Feat. Cabbie)_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3] => Array
    (
        [name] => dnb/21st Century (Feat. Cabbie)_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3
        [time] => 1296577357
        [size] => 8260946
        [hash] => 7fda7e838192f5c362f71ffff300a8c3
    )

[dnb/Abort_Delta Heavy_192.mp3] => Array
    (
        [name] => dnb/Abort_Delta Heavy_192.mp3
        [time] => 1296577451
        [size] => 8080602
        [hash] => bb71d713fd77746cd7debb39407ba88f
    )
```

here is the output.

```
    TheBeautifulSouth/2-15 One Last Love Song.m4anum2
    TheBeautifulSouth/2-16 Mirror.m4anum2
    TheBeautifulSouth/2-17 One God.m4anum2
    TheBeautifulSouth/2-18 Blackbird On the Wire (Radio Ed.m4anum2
    dnb/03 Twerk feat. Yo Majesty (Sub Focus Remix).mp3num2
    dnb/21st Century (Feat. Cabbie)_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3num2
    dnb/Better Place_Dub Zero_192.mp3num2
    dnb/Body_Shot_Tantrum_Desire_192.mp3num2
```

I am trying to put this into a menu structure as follows.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <ul>
        TheBeautifulSouth
        <li>2-15 One Last Love Song.m4anum2</li>
        <li>2-16 Mirror.m4anum2</li>
        <li>2-17 One God.m4anum2</li>
        <li>2-18 Blackbird On the Wire (Radio Ed.m4anum2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul>
        dnb
        <li>03 Twerk feat. Yo Majesty (Sub Focus Remix).mp3num2</li>
        <li>21st Century (Feat. Cabbie)_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3num2</li>
        <li>Better Place_Dub Zero_192.mp3num2</li>
        <li>Body_Shot_Tantrum_Desire_192.mp3num2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I am trying to use the php function strstr but can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
 <ul>
        <li>list
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($bucket_contents as $file){ 

       $fname = $file['name'];

       $list = strstr($fname, '/', true); ?>
                <li><?php echo $list; ?></li>
                <?php  } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the '/' character? Like this: '\/'. Other than that I can't see anyting that would cause a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variables have the values they should have (try a `var_dump`), the only problem I can see, is your php version. Are you sure your server is running php 5.3?

Note that the third parameter in `strstr` is only available in php 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

by using 
    strstr($fname, '/', true);

you're actually telling php to return everything **before** the character "/".
if you drop the "true", you'll receive everything **from**, including the "/" character.

you can do something like

```
$list = substr($fname, strpos($fname, "/") +1);
```